# SOAp API - InpersonSigner and Signer for same role

Tags: docusignapi

We have defined a template in Docusign. The template has 3 pre-defined roles. A reviewer and 2 signers.
In our use case, the reviewer will always get the email first, but the next 2(clients) could either be a 'Signer' or an 'In Person Signer'. We are setting the correct values while making an API call for the inPerson recipient(keeping the userName and email match that of an active DocuSign user), but observe that even though the email goes to the 'host' account we setup, the 'InPerson' signing experience does not kick in.
The response of the SOAP API gives the recipient type as "Signer". Could this be a permission issue for the DocuSign API user? We have lieterally tried to browse over all available documentation and have not come across anything useful

Also, we are unable to change the routing order through the SOAP UI - we want the reviewer to get the email first and all the clients in parallel, so have set the RoutingId to 1 for the reviewer and 2 for everyone else, but it is not working.
Please help

Comment: Please post the raw request XML that you are sending from your code.  You can redact any data that shouldn't be shared, like the document bytes for instance.

Comment: Thanks Ergin... good to see you again after docusign conference meet ................"Is it possible to change the recipient type defined for a existing template through the API - eg, change a recipient type to InPersonSigner from Signer at runtime.